# Rails query with more than two join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to join and get results from three table in json format

```
@employee = Employee.joins(:salary,:personal_info).select("salary.*,personal_info.*)  --> This works fine

@employee = Employee.joins(:salary,:personal_info,:loan).select("salary.*,personal_info.*,loan.*)  --> only salary and personal_info is coming

format.json { render json: @employee, serializer: EmployeeSerializer, :root => 'employee'}
```

Comment: a) What SQL query is generated in second case?
b) What is the association linking `Employee` with loan?

Comment: linking with employee_id for all the three

Answer (score 0):

try this by providing raw sql,

```
@employee = Employee.joins('INNER JOIN salary ON salary.employee_id = employee.id INNER JOIN personal_info ON personal_info.employee_id = employee.id INNER JOIN loan ON loan.employee_id = employee.id')
```

Comment: modified the answer, check now